# Issues with creating NuGet packages, requires other packages to be downloaded

Tags: .net, devops, nuget-package

I am not sure why this is happening, but it's driving me nuts.  We created a local NuGet package, inside this project we are doing some JSON modifying.  Then when it's done, it returns a .NET class.

The issue I'm running into, even though this should be a black box, when I reference this NuGet package, it throws an error because I need to add Newtonsoft JSON package.  Why would I need that if I'm not using JSON at all in the application, the NuGet package seems to rely on the consuming project to have the package.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I keep this NuGet package as a true "black-box" and not require the consuming application to reference the Newtonsoft package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the dependency as `PrivateAssets=all` to keep it as a development dependency, and it won't be transitively depended on by the consuming projects.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" PrivateAssets="all"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

### References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets